# Leaflet in R Shiny -- Custom Color Ramp for Tiled Data?

Tags: gdal2tiles, shiny, leaflet-r

I have large-ish grids (roughly 9000 x 9000 cells) of model results in single-band GeoTIFFs (re-projected from raw outputs in FLT in a different coordinate system). I am displaying them over a tiled background map in Shiny using leaflet -- specifically addRasterImage().

The modelers want to be able to pan and zoom to selected areas in these grids and adjust the display colors to highlight local variation in the results. I think I can provide this, but my solutions so far involve reloading the raster to change the colors, which takes a long time per change (loading the image at full resolution takes tens of seconds). Even without re-coloring, the response to pan and zoom is choppy and sluggish.[image: single-raster image]

To improve the performance, I used gdal2tiles (with default settings, because I'm new to this) to tile and pyramid my GeoTIFF. Now I can display the result with addTiles() instead of addRasterImage(). The new map is much more responsive, but I can't seem to choose a color ramp for addTiles, so my display is now in a chunky greyscale, and the grey-shading is different in from tile to tile.[image: tiled image]

First of all, I have to do something to make the color ramping consistent across the tiles. Is that a gdal2tiles setting? If so, which is it?

What I really want (Everything! I want Everything!) is the flexibility of addRasterImage() and the responsiveness of a tiled-and-pyramided image. Is that possilbe using the tools offered by leaflet and Shiny?